# MongoDB query performance with Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, es6-promise

currently I'm working on a personal project which i'm struggling with two ways of doing a query on MongoDB.

```
CustomerSchema.methods.GetOrders = function(){
    return Promise.all(
        this.orders.map(orderId => Order.findOne(orderId))
    );
};
// This will find all of an user order by their ObjectId

const orders = await Order.find({customerId:req.params});
```

My question is which one way is better and why? Or what are their pros and cons?

I tested here and the firt one method is performed in double time.

Comment: Your first one sends a query to the database for each id, whereas the second one sends a single query for a batch of ids. Obviously fewer queries tends to be better performing.

Answer (score 1):

The `find()` approach should be faster for numerous reasons. First, it sends one query as opposed to one for every order, so fewer round trips to the database. A much less significant performance impact also comes from the fact that you're creating a new [promise for every `findOne()` call](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne).

Also, I don't think `GetOrders()` as written actually works. I think you meant to use [`Order.findById(orderId)`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById), or `Order.findOne({ _id: orderId })`